# How to handle Node.js MySql ETIMEDOUT error?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, electron

I am trying to connect to an online hosted mysql database, so no localhost. But everytime i try to connect it gives me this error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (F:\FG\CO\CODESK\CO_PM\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:411:13)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:445:8)
at ontimeout (timers.js:427:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:289:5)
at listOnTimeout (timers.js:252:5)
at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:212:10)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (F:\FG\CO\CODESK\CO_PM\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
at Protocol.handshake (F:\FG\CO\CODESK\CO_PM\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
at Connection.connect (F:\FG\CO\CODESK\CO_PM\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:118:18)
at condb (file:///F:/FG/CO/CODESK/CO_PM/dist/:59:16)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///F:/FG/CO/CODESK/CO_PM/dist/:23:5)
at j (F:\FG\CO\CODESK\CO_PM\node_modules\scripts\jquery.min.js:2:29999)
at k (F:\FG\CO\CODESK\CO_PM\node_modules\scripts\jquery.min.js:2:30313)
at e.invokeTask (file:///F:/FG/CO/CODESK/CO_PM/dist/polyfills.c6871e56cb80756a5498.js:1:7780)
at t.runTask (file:///F:/FG/CO/CODESK/CO_PM/dist/polyfills.c6871e56cb80756a5498.js:1:2964)
at t.invokeTask (file:///F:/FG/CO/CODESK/CO_PM/dist/polyfills.c6871e56cb80756a5498.js:1:8870)
```

This is the code used for the connection:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');

//login credentials have been replaced with placeholders

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'thehost',
    user     : 'theuser',
    password : 'thepassword',
    database : 'thedb',
});

connection.connect();

$clientquery = "SELECT * FROM fa_ec_clients WHERE company_id = 'fc51b2dc49b0e4e76a90332f0e5cdafd'";

connection.query($clientquery, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) alert(error);
    console.log(results);
});

connection.end();
```

Is there anyone who has an idea how i could fix this?

Comment: It's the port 3306 enabled on the mysql host? Are you using Azure / AWS? Can you put the host url to check if the port is open?

Comment: @JoseMato Yes the port is enabled. but how can i find out if im using azure or AWS?

Comment: Hummm,where did you find that "mysql database"? Is not  managed by you?

Comment: @JoseMato it is managed by me. I have webshosting and that came with mysql databases. I use it a lot for my website using PHP and that works perfectly so i just do not get what te problem is here

Comment: thanks for the info. That is weird. I am using the same mysql npm library and this error happens because of internal network problems (no access to internet, etc) or having access to internet but mysql port / your ip is filtered on destiny. Can you check two things please?: 1. try to connect using mysql from terminal and 2. Try to write a quick php script to connect to same remote host. If step 1 or 2 fails then there is a problem with the provider or with your network (trying from other network would be nice too if step 1 and 2 fails)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, always check for an error return from `.connect()`:

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ', err);
    return;
  }
});
```

It will be easier to tell what's wrong that way, and you maybe can even write your code to recover.

Secondly, your connection request times out. That means the host at `thehost` is simply ignoring your request. Many hosting providers, especially those of the US$5 per month variety, only allow API access to their MySQL databases from within their own server farms. They configure their firewalls to ignore outside requests to internal-only services (like databases).

Some--not all--hosting providers offer a configuration setting to allow direct outside access to MySQL for their customers.  You should look at their help documentation, or ask a customer support rep about this.

Why do they do this? Security and multitenancy: many customers share a single MySQL server, and if a cybercreep manages to break in to MySQL, he might be able to crash the server or steal data.

Answer (score 0):

If it is on a VPS configured with CSF firewall, you need to whitelist your IP via SSH. Otherwise it still throws exactly above error even after adding via cPanel's Remote MYSql.

```
# csf -a <VPS-IP>
# csf -r
```

You can do it quickly via WHM too. Just posted as it may help somebody.